# Jquery tabs CSS conflict

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui, django-templates, pinax

I am trying to put a tabbed interface on a page of a Pinax project (Django). However, other elements of the page are already importing javascript and CSS which may be messing up my tabs.

here is the head of my page:

```
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>{% block head_title_base %}{% if SITE_NAME %}{{ SITE_NAME }} : {% endif %}{% block head_title %}{% endblock %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/extra.css"/>
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap-alerts.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap-twipsy.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap-tabs.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap-buttons.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/theme.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/pinax.modal.js"></script>
```

the tabs I am creating are just like the example in jquery website-

here is the html generated:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Text Analytics Workbench : Welcome</title>
    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/site_media/static/img/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/css/extra.css"/>
    <link href="/site_media/static/css/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="/site_media/static/js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/site_media/static/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/site_media/static/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script src="/site_media/static/js/bootstrap-alerts.js"></script>
    <script src="/site_media/static/js/bootstrap-twipsy.js"></script>
    <script src="/site_media/static/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="/site_media/static/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="/site_media/static/js/bootstrap-tabs.js"></script>
    <script src="/site_media/static/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="/site_media/static/js/bootstrap-buttons.js"></script>
    <script src="/site_media/static/js/theme.js"></script>
    <script src="/site_media/static/js/pinax.modal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   /* $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });*/
</script>
</head>
<body class="home" id="">
        <div class="topbar">
            <div class="fill">
                <div class="container">
                        <h3><a href="/">Text Analytics Workbench</a></h3>
    <ul><li id="tab_profile"><a href="/profiles/profile/fccoelho/">Profile</a></li><li id="tab_notices"><a href="/notices/">Notices</a></li></ul>
                        <ul class="secondary-nav">

    <li>
        <a href="#" class="menu">fccoelho</a>
        <ul class="menu-dropdown">
            <li><a href="/account/email/">Account</a></li>

                <li><a href="/admin/">Admin</a></li>

            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="/account/logout/">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>               
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="hero-unit">
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Search</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Document View</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Corpus View</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
        <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">

            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sed viverra dui. Aenean blandit faucibus tincidunt. Phasellus fermentum elit ut erat varius cursus. Nunc posuere mauris sit amet enim congue quis elementum lectus tincidunt. Cras vel tempus metus.</p>
            <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>

        </div>
        <div class="span4">

            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sed viverra dui. Aenean blandit faucibus tincidunt. Phasellus fermentum elit ut erat varius cursus. Nunc posuere mauris sit amet enim congue quis elementum lectus tincidunt. Cras vel tempus metus.</p>
            <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>

        </div>
        <div class="span4">

            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sed viverra dui. Aenean blandit faucibus tincidunt. Phasellus fermentum elit ut erat varius cursus. Nunc posuere mauris sit amet enim congue quis elementum lectus tincidunt. Cras vel tempus metus.</p>
            <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>

        </div>
        <div class="span4">

            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sed viverra dui. Aenean blandit faucibus tincidunt. Phasellus fermentum elit ut erat varius cursus. Nunc posuere mauris sit amet enim congue quis elementum lectus tincidunt. Cras vel tempus metus.</p>
            <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="container">
```

© 2011 Leximath

```
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you include the actual generated HTML and all other relevant JS and CSS? Otherwise it would be difficult/impossible to tell what is happening from reading a list of files you're including with your page. Also, have you considered using [Bootstrap's tab plugin](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs) instead?

Comment: You might have to go through the bootstrap css that you're including and find the offending styles. Also if you're not using the bootstraps tabs why are you including their corresponding js? Have you tried inspecting the tabs elements to see which css is overriding the correct jquery css?

Comment: Why not use bootstrap tabs ? http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Curiously enough, just moving the jquery-ui stuff (js and CSS) to the header of a derived template instead of the base template, solved all conflicts.

here is how the (working) rendered head looks like now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Text Analytics Workbench : Welcome</title>
    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/site_media/static/img/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/css/extra.css"/>

    <script src="/site_media/static/js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/site_media/static/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script src="/site_media/static/js/bootstrap-alerts.js"></script>
    <script src="/site_media/static/js/bootstrap-twipsy.js"></script>
    <script src="/site_media/static/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="/site_media/static/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="/site_media/static/js/bootstrap-tabs.js"></script>
    <script src="/site_media/static/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="/site_media/static/js/bootstrap-buttons.js"></script>
    <script src="/site_media/static/js/theme.js"></script>
    <script src="/site_media/static/js/pinax.modal.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!--<script src="/site_media/static/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>-->
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/site_media/static/css/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
   /* $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });*/
</script>
</head>
```